# Show particular event occurrence details

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I have a calendar showing all upcoming events, many of which are occurrences of an event (example: weekly basketball on Thursdays from 6 to 9pm).

If the user selects the third occurrence of this event, it still shows the event details for the first upcoming occurrence rather than date & time info for the third one.

Example:
First occurrence July 13 6-9pm
Second occurrence July 20 6-9pm
Third occurrence July 27 6-9pm

If the user selects the third occurrence and clicks on the event, the event page that comes up shows July 13 6-9 and not July 27 6-9...how do I pull a specific occurrence for an event when it is selected from a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Recurrences are just simulated based on rules, so they don't have unique event/entry ID's. Because of this, there isn't a real clean way to pinpoint each occurrence like you ask. However, the workaround is to send the date segments along with it in the URL so you can sort of manipulate the template to appear like it's showing the date for that specific recurrence.

Check out the demo templates that come with Calendar to see how this is done. :)

Comment: Interesting..this creates more issues though. We have most recent upcoming events shown on home page but with occurrences, it also shows the wrong date (initial date of the event rather than occurrence date). So what happens is that occurrences show as past dates even when their occurrences happen in the future (aka are upcoming). Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Depends which version of Calendar you're using...